# SVG mask stroke color

Tags: html, css, svg

I really hope someone here can help me out, since i'm stuck for 3 days straight now.

I have a header image with half a circle cut out by using a SVG mask, this half circle needs to have a colored stroke but since it's a mask it won't let me do this. I have tried and searched everything, and came upon this codepen snippet which is using the SVG use tag: https://codepen.io/rewfergu/pen/oJCif
However, i can not get this to work at all.

Here is my SVG code including the white transparent stroke (as far as i got):

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel carousel-fade slide myCarousel-slide" style="height:auto; max-height:499px; overflow:hidden">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div id="slide2" class="item active" data-navpos="" data-navposarrow="" data-center="1" data-maxheight="499" data-id="2" style="height:499px;"><img id="slideimg2" class="logofull img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1800x499.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
     circle {
        stroke: #942994;
        stroke-width: 5;
     }
    ]]></style>
     <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
       <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
       <circle id="c1" cx="50%" cy="105%" r="180" fill="#000"/>
     </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.7"/>
</svg>
```

And my  CSS, applied on my header image (the carousel is 100% width and around 500px high):

```
#myCarousel .item {
border-bottom: 5px solid #942994;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
mask: url(#mask);
}
```

Unfortunately i can not use PNG's, because the header images need to be easily changable.

Update:
Created a new fiddle with my exact setup:  https://jsfiddle.net/oqfdfart/2/
Also some strange behaviour: In Chrome, Edge and IE the half circle does not appear at all in the headerimage.

Update:
I found the answer, following my latest fiddle i've separated both SVG's like so:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
   #inner {
   stroke: #942994;
   stroke-width: 5;
   fill-opacity: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
   }
  ]]></style>
   <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
     <circle id="c1" cx="50%" cy="105%" r="180" fill="#000"/>
   </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.7"/>
</svg>
<svg id="innercircle" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0">
  <circle id="inner" x="0" y="0" cx="50%" cy="105%" r="181" fill="#fff" />
</svg>
```

And added the following CSS:

```
#headeroverlay {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top:0;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
height: 499px;
z-index: -1;
}

#innercircle {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

First i had a very dark overlay on top of my headerimage, but this was fixed by giving #headeroverlay the z-index -1.
Maybe this solution is not so pretty since i had to define a fixed height for my headersection, but at least for this project that's no problem.
If someone has a better solution i'm very curious :)

Also i'm still stuck with Chrome, Edge and IE not rendering my SVG's at all.

Comment: Ok, I played around a bit in jsfiddle with your example. https://jsfiddle.net/ojvaevLs/
I am not that familiar with SVG but perhabs the jsfiddle will help you forward.

Comment: Hi Joeri, thanks for looking at my problem. I have tried your code, but it instead shows the half circle without a border at all. I realized i didn't include my carousel HTML, so i have now added this to my original post. When adding my HTML to your fiddle, it shows no border at all. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Masks only affect the translucency of the element it is applied to.

If you want to outline the hole with a colour, then you'll need to create an element the same shape as the hole, then draw it on top of the masked element.

Comment: Hi Paul, i think this is what Joeri tried to do in his fiddle but when applied to my case it doesn't do/show anything. Any thoughts on what i'm doing wrong? (I have of course tried to define the second circle outside of the mask)

Comment: If you post or link what you did, it'll be easier for us to tell you what you did wrong :)

Comment: Hi Paul, I have created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dpp4q4om/5/
Somehow the second circle gets moved all the way down, in my actual design it's not visible at all anymore. (I will try to provide a better link later today'

Comment: Alright, i have updated my question with a new fiddle :) This is exactly how i have it, just cleaned my code as much as possible to avoid clutter :)

Comment: And what is the final version supposed to look like?  That is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the purple border is supposed to continue inside the half cirle. There is some strange behaviour though, i checked in chrome and then the half circle (without the border) doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Do you actually need an invisible cut-out?  It would be easier if, say, you could position an element the colour of the page background on top of the carousel.

Comment: Unfortunately i do, in my actual project i have a page background image that needs to be visible through the hole.